# 'Javascript' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 5, position 18

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I'm trying to load a Rss XML page of this page :
http://www.cairo360.com/xml/feeds/rss/Cairo360Events.xml

but i got this error:
'Javascript' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 5, position 18.

Here's is the code:

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri("http://www.cairo360.com/xml/feeds/rss/Cairo360Events.xml"));

```
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

knowing that I tried this code with a different Rss xml page and it worked!

Comment: "I tried this code with a different Rss xml page and it worked"  That's not enough to prove a program's correctness.  Writing a program that's correct for one input is often easy, but writing a program that's correct for *all* inputs is a different story.

Comment: I'm here because of a similar problem. All roads in Google have no answers but all appear to be XML-parser related. Our version of the issue doesn't happen in all of our environments. As a primarily JavaScript developer, I have no !@#$ing idea how the token 'javascript' finds its way into .NET's XML parser. In our case it's breaking in the middle of a web service request. I currently have no reason to believe anything found its way into the mix from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(@"http://www.cairo360.com/xml/feeds/rss/Cairo360Events.xml"));
```

in C# anything after a "/" in a string is a special character. For example "/n" is new line. By using the "@" in front of a string double quote it says, ignore all special transformation characters. You could have also done this.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(@"http:////www.cairo360.com//xml//feeds//rss//Cairo360Events.xml"));
```

In C# a "//" in a string is then turned into a single "/". The double "//" tells the compiler no special character, treat this as a single slash.

Never add both a "@" and a "//", for @ already ignores special characters so "//" really does mean "//".

Hope this helps.

EDIT

Also try this

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://www.cairo360.com/xml/feeds/rss/Cairo360Events.xml");

        // Skip non-significant whitespace  
        reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant;

        // Read nodes one at a time  
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Print out info on node  
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.NodeType.ToString(), reader.Name);
        }
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem..the program throws the exception at the last line :
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

Comment: @Landin, I believe you've got your '/' and '\' confused.